# Doubt regarding inclined plane in Feynman lectures

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I recently read something in the Feynman lectures which I find difficult to understand. Imagine an inclined plane on the top of which is a smooth pulley. There is a weight hanging from the pulley and another weight at the base of the inclined plane on the other side. Feynman says since the weights are just balanced, the system is reversible and the weights can move up and down?

What does Feynman mean here and why is the word reversible significant here? Also if the weights are balanced how can they move up and down?

Comment: It would save us some time if you gave the specific chapter from the 3-volume Red Books.  But in brief, I suspect the meaning is that the system is dynamically balanced regardless of the initial position of the two weights.

Comment: It's the first volume in gravitational potential energy

Comment: @user34304 As with the Bible, it's much more convenient to cite the book, chapter, and verse when you're trying to locate a passage in the Big Red Books. E.g., the 'Gravitational potential energy' is section 2 of chapter 4 of Book I, so you'd write (I.4:2) ;)

Comment: Suggestion: link to the online version.

Answer (score -1):

The point I think book is trying to make is that **Dynamic Equilibrium** exists in this particular case.

Let's assume mass to be m1 and m2.

acceleration = (m1-m2)×g/(m1+m2)

According to your given excerpt m1=m2
So acceleration would be zero.

So even when slight change in position occurs it counters that as in
[Positive  Equilibrium](https://images.app.goo.gl/uQe7WmVSCPTKCBhU6)